# Django ORM annotation on prefetch_related

Tags: mysql, django, django-orm

How can I annotate a related model during prefetch_related query?

I have two models:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    ...

class Student(models.Model):
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subject, related_name="students")
```

I want to retrieve in a single query `Subject` objects, the `Student` objects related to each one and number of `Subject`s each `Student` has.
I am trying to accomplish it with the following query:

`Subject.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    Prefetch("student", queryset=Student.objects.all().annotate(subjects_count=Count("subject")))
)`

But I get an SQL error:

`OperationalError at /concerts/coldplay-en-madrid/
(1055, "Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'studentsubject.subject_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by")`

Comment: Try doing this instead:
Subject.objects.annotate(subjects_count=Count('students')).prefetch_related('students')

Comment: That way I get the number of students each subject has, but I want to get the reverse relation: How many subjects each student has. Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

So, as per your requirement, you can make a 'through' table for handling your M2M relationship between Subject and Students. So, your models would look something like:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    # ...

class Student(models.Model):
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(
                   to=Subject,
                   through='StudentSubject',
                   related_name="students")

class StudentSubject(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(to=Student, related_name='student_subjects')
    subject = models.ForeignKey(to=Subject, related_name='subject_students')
```

You can read more about through tables from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).
Now, you can query like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count
students = Student.objects.prefetch_related('student_subjects')

subjects_associated_with_students = (
    students.annotate(num_subjects=Count('student_subjects'))
```

`subjects_associated_with_students` is a queryset with which, you can now do any regular operation. For ex- `subjects_associated_with_students.filter(num_subjects__gt=1)`. This will give you all the students who has at least 1 subject.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think this is not the right answer.. I want to get `Subject` objects, but with this solution I'd be getting `Students`. Thanks!